# Tools for java web applications?

Tags: java

What are the different ways to create a web-application in Java? Are there tools available other than straight-up servlets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open source web frameworks in Java and related view technologies:

- [Tapestry](http://tapestry.apache.org/)
- [Apache Cocoon](http://cocoon.apache.org/)
- [Apache MyFaces](http://myfaces.apache.org/)
- [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/)
- [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)
- [Java Server Faces (JSF)](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/)
- [Apache Struts](http://struts.apache.org/)
- [Turbine](http://turbine.apache.org/)
- [Seam](http://www.seamframework.org/Home)
- [Makumba](http://www.makumba.org/)
- [Java Server Pages (JSP)](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/)
- [Stripes](http://www.stripesframework.org/)
- [OpenXava](http://www.gestion400.com/web/guest/home)
- [JPublish](http://jpublish.org/)
- wingS
- Strecks
- AribaWeb
- Echo
- [RIFE](https://rife.dev.java.net/)
- Anvil
- WebOnSwing
- Click
- ThinWire
- [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/)
- [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/)

Check http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks for more options and to read a brief overview of each one.

Comment: JSP and Facelets are view technologies, not frameworks. Everything just runs on top of JSP. Facelets is for JSF only.

Answer (score 3):

There are many many web frameworks for Java that allow you to build Web Applications. The vast majority are built on top of the Servlet API, but provide a layer of abstraction that you interact with instead of dealing with servlets directly

My favourite (for what its worth) is [Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org)

Answer (score 2):

An quite old and simple standard is CGI, and java can do that: http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/CGI-with-Java.html

A more recommended today would be to use a web-framework. These usually abstract from the Servlet API and provide a ground for common patterns in web development.

Here is a quite long list of available choices: http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks

Comment: Plain CGI seems like a step backwards from Servlets, which already encapsulate all the request/response stuff from CGI.

Answer (score 2):

In java there's also [Facelets](https://facelets.dev.java.net/), [JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/) and many other frameworks, like [Spring MVC](http://www.springsource.org/).

Comment: I'm surprised JSP isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

JuanZe gives a good answer with the list of frameworks.  Here's some more detail.

I'd say take a look at [Struts](http://struts.apache.org/), as it's one of the oldest and simplest frameworks.  Struts v1 and v2 are two different beasts; Struts v1.0 was written mostly in a day, and you can learn it in an hour, and might be a very good introduction to web frameworks.

I currently use [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/), and wouldn't go back to Struts from there.  The nice part of Spring is that it comes with the framework (Spring MVC), but there are dozens of other "nice to have" components that really help you out as you continue to learn 'em.

Other developers I work with complain regularly that [Seam](http://seamframework.org/) is the way to go.  They've said some pretty intelligent things in the past, but I really like Spring, and our project is married to it.

[Wicket](http://wicket.apache.org/) also looks interesting; Spring is very heavy on XML, and Wicket gets rid of that, which is a very happy thought.  That said, there's a pretty huge gain with some of the XML in Spring, so I'd worry about losing that.

As an addition, I'd take a look at [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/), formerly called Jakarta Commons.  It's a collection of useful libraries of stuff that probably should be included in the core Java API.  Discursive has a [wonderful book](http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/book-cjcook.html) that walks you through it.

Comment: Oh man.  Being married to Spring is not a defense or valid reason, it's a linchpin and architectural shortcoming.  One feature of Seam that is cool is that it supports Scaffolding and ActiveRecord a la Ruby.  Hype aside, having canned CRUD functionality is pretty sweet.

Comment: I have half a million lines of code running on Spring; I'm not switching the framework at this point.  I'm willing to use Seam on new projects, but moving to it on the current project would be suicide on several levels.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you are asking about tools interface to develop a web application.i suggest eclipse coz its  too convenient to use,flexible and can run on pcs with low configurations.i have just 512 mb ram and i m using it easily

Answer (score 0):

As a quickstart you could download Netbeans http://netbeans.org/ , you can try almost all kinds of J2EE technologies with a preconfigured app-server and database using included sample projects. It tooks only seconds to build and run and if you like analyze the code.

Answer (score 0):

and here there is another one, a very young one this time: [(µ)Micro](http://micro-docs.simplegames.ca/). It is open source, Apache 2 license, and available on Github. I built this framework for fun and I was trying to port and simulate as much functionality as I could from my experience as a Sinatra/Rails developer. Cheers!